# 4W Electrical DC power from propane

Tags: power, generator, peltier

I'm looking for a way to generate around 4W of electrical power (**12VDC, 350mA**, to be specific) with an efficiency of around 10% in a small and safe package.

The background of the question is that I want to use the propane (10-20g/h) to generate CO2 for a small mosquito trap (Biogents Mosquitaire) and at the same time produce the electrical power to run the fan of the trap.

What options are there?

- Are there off-the-shelf thermoelectric generators of that size that run on propane? I have found none. I could probably build one but it's not trivial to make a compact device that is inexpensive, safe, and reliable. The gas flow must somehow be feedback-controlled to run the TE-element at a good point while making sure not to overheat. Combustion must be complete, as residual propane or carbon monoxide might repel the mosquitoes.
- Are there experimental fuel cell kits that can run on air and propane? The commercial ones I found are too big by several orders of magnitude with the one by Inergio coming closest (50W, but not yet commercially available).

Comment: What has your studies shown you on this topic? You've written very little. About as much as one might, had they done no study at all but have an idea. Put some elbow grease into your own thoughts. Give us something that shows how much you care. (Hint: Look up DPFC, PEMFC, PAFC, & SOFC.) Meanwhile, I like the idea of a small RTG. ;)

Comment: Also, consider contacting UTC Fuel Cells. They are a division of United Technologies Corporation and they specialize in H3PO4 (phosphoric acid) methods. I'm sure they can point you in the right direction. What you want is kind of a unicorn.

Comment: How much propane are you burning? Would somethink like a simple Peltier TEG suffice? https://3aa600ba-0987-4229-a327-28948e71f957.usrfiles.com/ugd/3aa600_4f3aa7c9fc3c4b44b03766be1af3a11d.pdf

Comment: A stirling engine can run a fan off the heat produced by a burner, no electricity. I don't think there are commercial small stirling engines, but many hobbyists have made their own.

Comment: Can I suggest that you try it first.  Because the mosquitos are not attracted to heat, UV or CO2.  I have tried many traps.  The only one that is effective uses a lure that smells like sweat.

Comment: @RohitGupta yes,  this has been tested, by myself also. Of the two species of mosquitos we have here, one (Aedes albopictus) is strongly attracted by CO2 in addition to the smell (which is also part of the trap), and the other (Culex pipiens) is almost exclusively attracted to CO2.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks, that's an interesting idea indeed that might get around some of the complications.  I'll look into this.